# How does code calculate square?

Tags: c, algorithm

How loop work in this example specially if odd is initialize to value 3 than how it get incremented to get square?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i, n, odd, square;

    printf("This program prints a table of squares.\n");
    printf("Enter number of entries in table :");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    i = 1;
    odd = 3;
    for(square = 1; i <= n; odd += 2){
        printf("%10d%10d\n", i, square);
        i++;
        square += odd;
    }
return 0;
}
```

I need step by step clarification please help

Comment: Homework? Get a pencil and paper and write the values down. Follow the code

Comment: What does `square` and `odd` have to do with the loop conditional and counter? Nothing. And a pencil and sheet of paper will answer your question.

Comment: please read the process how for loop works

Comment: [`Show that the sum of the largest odd divisors of n + 1, n + 2, …, 2n(where n is a natural number) is a perfect square?`](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263101/prove-every-odd-integer-is-the-difference-of-two-squares/263108#263108)

Answer (score 6):

This is using a math trick.  The sum of the first N odd numbers is always a square.

For example:

```
1
1 + 3 = 4
1 + 3 + 5 = 9
1 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 16
```

`odd` is initially set to 3, and `square` starts at 1.

Everytime through the loop, `square` is printed, then `odd` is added to `square`, then 2 is added to `odd`, making it the next odd number.

Comment: Interesting math trick, never seen it before.

Comment: interesting to me to know this

Comment: @DonRoby - I thought that was very imaginative of the lecturer.

Comment: @MarkRansom this is also interesting [Prove every odd integer is the difference of two squares](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263101/prove-every-odd-integer-is-the-difference-of-two-squares/263108#263108)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan - That's a nice visualization of these two related facts.

Comment: This comes from the expansion of [(x+1)^2 - x^2].

Comment: Look at the sum of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression with a1=1 and d=2

Answer (score 0):

Since we are starting from 1

At First the `square = 1` i.e, `square^2` and `odd = 3` i.e, `2*square+1`
so, the next would be square^2+2*square+1 -> (square+1)^2

so in general it would be `square^2+2*n+sumOfOddNum(n)`

where, `sumOfOddNum(n)` is sum of first n oddnumbers which as pointed out is n^2

so, `square^2+2*n*square+n^2` [square=1] will become `(square+n)^2`